# What is the member in brackets [...] when viewing in `Watch`?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, watch

As the below snapshot when debugging, I see members listed between brackets. What are they?

[image]

Comment: Wow.. SO really has all the answers... I literally googled _visual studio debugger square brackets_ and this answer showed up!

Answer (score 4):

Inside the brackets the actual runtime type of the object can be found. Outside the brackets the reference type can be found.

[Difference Between Object Type and Reference Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730109/difference-between-object-type-and-reference-type)

Comment: what about the Type, what is inside the braces. e.g. `object {PhysicsEditorHelper}`. I cannot find a definition of `PhysicsEditorHelper` in the C# codebase. But seems like it is a c++ classes.