# Issue on Comparing String and Object value Java

Tags: java, string, oop

I am getting one String value by using Scanner class in Java. Value stores in the field "name".
I am using StringBuilder class for my logical operation and it finally stores one string value. The field name is "sb".
At last, both the field holds the same value. I tried to compare the values by using .equals() and it didn't help me. Kindly refer the code on below and please help me to overcome this issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter String: ");
    String name = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = name.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(name.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(sb);
    if (name.equals(sb)) {
        System.out.println(name + " --> Palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println(name + " --> Not a Palindrome");
    }
}
```

Output:

Enter String:

madam

madam

madam

madam --> Not a Palindrome

Comment: `name.equals(sb.toString())`.  `sb` is not a `String`, and if you compare a `String` to a non-`String` they will never be equal.

Comment: Thank you. It's working fine. Could you please tell me that field sb also holds "madam" right. then why we need to use .toString().

Comment: Because a `StringBuilder` is not a `String`.

Comment: Because you have to compare a `String` to another `String`, and a `StringBuilder` is not a `String`.

Comment: Because when you pass a StringBuilder, Object's version of .equals is used instead of String's.

Comment: By the way, you may be interested in [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()).

Comment: you can use `name.contentEquals(sb)`

Comment: @KCWong Technically, it's `String`'s implementation here.

Comment: thanks all for support