# Palindrome java error

Tags: java, regex, syntax-error, palindrome, replaceall

I have a problem in Java. I am making a program to check if a given text is Palindrome or not. I am 99% sure my code is correct yet I can't get a good result. Here is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    System.out.print("Enter a line of text to check if palindrome: ");
    String text = scan.nextLine();
    String revText = text.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").toLowerCase().trim(); /*
                                                                      * Using regex here... everything that is not
                                                                      * (^) from A-Z (capital) to a-z replace with
                                                                      * ("") in revText.
                                                                      */
    sb.append(revText).reverse().toString();

    System.out.println("Reversed: " + sb);
    System.out.println("Normal: " + revText);

    System.out.println(sb.equals(revText));

    scan.close();
}
```

So for instance I enter:

```
Enter a line of text to check if palindrome: Anna2023
Reversed: anna 
Normal: anna
false
```

Why false ? ;/

Comment: "I am 99% sure my code is correct yet I can't get a good result."  Ummm... if you can't get a good result, then I'm 100% sure your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
System.out.println(revText.equals(sb.toString()));
```

`sb` is not equal to the string because it is not a `String`. It is a container for building a string. The reason printing sb shows the `String` is that `System.out.println` will call `toString` on whatever is given to it.

Comment: Yap I you are right my bad thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` class does not override `equals` method from `Object` class.Hence it's equals method will check if object references are same and if those are same then only it will return true.In case of `String` class, it overrides equals method from object class and it checks if contents of two strings are equal.

In your code, you are calling `equals` method on `StringBuilder` object and as both references are different it is returning false.
Convert it to string and then call `equals()`,

```
System.out.println(sb.toString().equals(revText));
```

[Java .equals between String and StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544830/java-equals-between-string-and-stringbuilder)