# Using ((Base)this).f(); instead of `super.f()` in Derived.f() compiles fine but causes StackOverflowError in Runtime

Tags: java, polymorphism

Using `((Base)this).f();` instead of `super.f()` in Derived.f() compiles fine but causes StackOverflowError in Runtime. Why?

```
class Base {
    void f() {
        System.out.println("Base.f()");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    void f() {
        ((Base)this).f(); //instead of super.f();
        System.out.println("Derived.f()");
    }
}

public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Derived().f();;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `((Base)this)` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: As per your link, this is definitely not a duplicate! I would appreciate if anybody pointed to a true duplicate thou!

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a duplicate is. The answer there states: _Any method is dispatched (selected/invoked) dynamically according to the actual type of the object in stead of the type by which it is being referred to._ That's the answer to your question here, regardless of the `StackOverflowError`. That's just a side effect.

Comment: The typecasting of `this` to reference type `Base` has no effect; the object type is still `Derived`, so `Derived.f()` is called, thus `Derived.f()` is calling itself, causing a `StackOverflowError`. `(Supertype) this` is not the same as `super`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16730147/507738).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `f()` of `Derived` overrides `f()` of `Base`, in runtime `f()` of `Derived` (and not `f()` of `Base`) is executed even if you are invoking it via a reference to type `Base`.

Therefore

```
void f() {
    ((Base)this).f();
    System.out.println("Derived.f()");
}
```

is equivalent to

```
void f() {
    f();
    System.out.println("Derived.f()");
}
```

Your `f()` method is calling itself, which results in `StackOverflowError`.