# Java typecast with covariant return type

Tags: java, inheritance

I've create a small example for inheritance with covariant return type. There are basicly three different classes:

MainApp:

```
public class MainApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  BaseManager manager = new BirdManager();
  BirdManager birds = (BirdManager) manager.getManager(); // <-- Why type cast here
  // prints BirdManager
  }
}
```

BaseManager:

```
public abstract class BaseManager {
  private Map<ManagerType, BaseManager> list = new EnumMap<>(ManagerType.class);
  protected Map<ManagerType, BaseManager> getList() {
    return list;
  }
  public abstract BaseManager getManager();
}
```

BirdManager:

```
public class BirdManager extends BaseManager {
  public BirdManager getManager() {
    if (!super.getList().containsKey(ManagerType.BIRD)) {
        super.getList().put(ManagerType.BIRD, this);
    }
    return (BirdManager) super.getList().get(ManagerType.BIRD);
}
```

Why do I need to typecast `BaseManager` to `BirdManager` when I override the methode `getManager()` to return a `BirdManager`?

I've used [Can overridden methods differ in return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type) as reference.

**EDIT:**

I've different SubModels which all inherit from `BaseManager`. All models are allowed to exists once. Instead of using Singletons for each model I tryed to add these models to a list. With the `getManager()` I would like to get the actual model. Maybe I've to overthink my design.

Comment: That is because `manager` is of type `BaseManager`, so the compiler only 'knows' that `manager.getManager()` returns a `BaseManager`. The signature of `BaseManager.getManager()` confirms that. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730109/difference-between-object-type-and-reference-type). Why do you need the `getManager()` method anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `manager` object you are calling your method on is a `BaseManager`, not the `BirdManager`. Compiler doesn't know that you are actually calling a method of `BirdManager`, it will only be known at runtime, that's why you need a cast.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Is there any way to avoid the typecast with a certain pattern or maybe generics? Or is typecasting in this case "good enough"?

Comment: I don't really see the point of `getManager()` method, but maybe something like this in `BaseManager` class: `public <T> T getManager() { return (T) this; }`. I don't suggest using this, it's just a possibility, it breaks the entire purpose of generics (compile-time type safety).

Answer (score 0):

Because manager is an instance of BaseManager and not BirdManager. So that you can use it with birds instance you need to typecast it.