# Declared type vs Object type

Tags: java

So I am confused about Declared vs Object types. For example:
`Animal creature = new Mammal( new Vertebrate)` 
I know that the declared type is Animal, but what would the object type be? Mammal or Vertebrate?

Comment: Your example is really bad, why would the `Mammal` constructor take a `Vertebrate` parameter? Not to mention your syntax is wrong there, so I suggest not coming up with your own examples. Read some good tutorials instead.

Comment: I am confused, the above isn't valid java syntax. Do you mean `Animal creature = new Mammal( new Vertebrate())`? If so, yes, it is Mammal. Note that the `new  Vertebrate()` also creates a new object, but that is directly passed to the constructor of the Mammal class, that is all there is to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between Object Type and Reference Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730109/difference-between-object-type-and-reference-type)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thumb rule:

Declared type is whatever is on the left and side of the `=`, while object type is whatever is after the `new` keyword. In your case, declared type would be `Animal`, whereas object type would be `Mammal`. `Vertebrae` does not play any role here apart from calling the parameterised ctor of Mammal class.

Thumb Definitions:

Object Type: Whatever class' ctor you use to instantiate an object
Declared Type: Whatever the storage class of the variable you declare to be

Answer (score 0):

As others have said Mammal, you can verify this by printing out .getClass()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal mammal = new Mammal(new Vertebrate());
    Animal animal = new Animal();

    System.out.println(mammal.getClass());
    System.out.println(animal.getClass());

    if (mammal instanceof Animal) {
      System.out.println("mammal is animal");
    }
    if (mammal instanceof Mammal) {
      System.out.println("mammal is mammal");
    }
    if (animal instanceof Animal) {
      System.out.println("animal is animal");
    }
    if (animal instanceof Mammal) {
      System.out.println("animal is mammal");
    }
  }
```

output:

```
class Scratch$Mammal
class Scratch$Animal
mammal is animal
mammal is mammal
animal is animal
```